# Getting the values from a grouped row using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following class:

```
public class MySeat
{
  public string Section { get; set; }
  public string Row { get; set; }
  public string Seat {get; set; }
}
```

I want to group a list of seats by the Section and Row so that I can make a comma seperated list of the seats.

```
var groupedSeats = seats.GroupBy(x => new { x.Section, x.Row });
foreach (var group in groupedSeats)
{
  htmlWriter.Write(group.Key.Section);
  List<string> seatNumbers = new List<string>();
  foreach (var seat in group)
    seatNumbers.Add(seat.Seat);

  htmlWriter.Write(string.Join(@", ", seatNumbers.ToArray()));
}
```

Is there a better way to do this with LINQ?

This is just a small portion of the code I'm trying to clean up, I'm curious if there is a better way to grab the seat numbers for display rather than creating a list, looping through the groups and then doing a `string.Join` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to write

```
group.Select(s => s.Seat).ToArray()
```

Comment: Bah, I suck. I thought I tried that and it printed out the object type string rather than the actual seat numbers. Thanks, I'll accept in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a query that will build up all the strings directly, separating the "data construct" from the "processing construct":

```
var data = from grp in seats.GroupBy(x => new { x.Section, x.Row })
           let groupSeats = grp.Select(s => s.Seat).ToArray()
           select new {
              grp.Key.Section, 
              SeatNumbers = String.Join(@", ", groupSeats);

foreach (var d in data)
{
    htmlWriter.Write(d.Section);
    htmlWriter.Write(d.SeatNumbers);
}
```